# Right way to get value of query parameters nginx

Tags: nginx

How to get value of both query parameters (attribute and category) in nginx?

Example link:

example.com/?attribute=2&category=1

My nginx code:

```
if ($args ~ "attribute=(\d+)") {
        set $attribute $1;
}

if ($args ~ "category=(\d+)") {
        set $category $1;
}
```

In this way i can get only attribute value.

Comment: If i set "category" first in query i will get it in nginx, but not attribute value. How to get them both?

Answer (score 2):

The individual arguments are available as variables beginning with `$arg_`. For example:

```
$arg_attribute
$arg_category
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_arg_) for details.